# Can I use a FTC regulation phone to use the camera on multiple tasks?

Tags: wheeled-robot, computer-vision, cameras

**PREFACE:**

**THIS QUESTION REGARDS FTC ROBOTICS**
I am aware that a question similar to this exists on SE and I have looked at it, but the solutions provided did not solve my problem, and the nature of my question has additional constraints and criteria involved that make this a distinct problem.

**PROBLEM:**

I have been put in charge of creating java classes to add to an existing app, used to control a robot (FTC robotics, for those who are wondering). The features I have been given to add to the app include:

1. Shape detection (provided by FTC, all I need to do is tweak some
   files)
2. Automatically record and save a video in the background of the app using the back camera

**QUESTION:**

I was wondering, if this is even possible, how I would go about both recording video and using shape detection? How do I even record a video from the background of an app? If i cannot achieve both I was told to prioritize recording, as we have substitutes for shape detection.

**SPECS:**

Motorola moto g 2nd gen with Android Marshmallow

Or as a fallback:

ZTE speed with Android Marshmallow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCV is a comprehensive vision processing library with an Android port. It should work fine for both of your needs.